# How does "expect" work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I am trying to create a logic test using mocha and chai

```
var helperFunctions = require('../lib/helperfunctions.js');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

suite('Sample logic tests',function(){
    test('getDynamicContent() should return dynamic content',function(){
       console.log(typeof helperFunctions.getDynamicContent()); // string
       expect(false); //Doesnt seem to do anything
       expect(typeof helperFunctions.getDynamicContent() === 'number'); 
    });
});
```

My helperFunctions.js:

```
exports.getDynamicContent = function(){

    var dynamicContentSource = [
        "Dynamic Content 1",
        "Dynamic Content 2",
        "Dynamic Content 3",
        "Dynamic Content 4",
        "Dynamic Content 5"
    ];
    var randomDynamicContent = dynamicContentSource[Math.floor(Math.random()*dynamicContentSource.length)];
    return randomDynamicContent;
};
```

For some reason, my test always passes, even though typeof helperFunctions.getDynamicContent() is a string.

Can someone explain to me what I have not understood?

Comment: Most assertion APIs look like this: `expect(actual).to.be(expected)` . You are not using any matcher. http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are suppose to use a matcher like the above comment said. `expect().to.be.equal()` for example